# Content script is not getting message

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

My background script is opening a new tab, and then executing jQuery on this tab, then I execute my script and send my message that this script needs.

The thing is that script is not receiving the message.

***`background.js`***

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: myUrl}, function(tab){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'jquery-2.1.4.min.js'}, function(){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'myScript.js'});
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {myMessage: message.myMessage});
            })
        });
```

***`myScript.js`***

```
alert('It works!');

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    alert('Also here!');
});
```

So "It works!" pops out but "Also here!" does not.

Comment: Do you have the permission to access the `myUrl` domain? Here's what happens when you don't: `Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.` Have you checked the chrome debugger for the background page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `chrome.tabs.executeScript` is async, you also have to wait for `myScript.js` to be loaded before you send messages to it:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: myUrl}, function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'jquery-2.1.4.min.js'}, function(){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'myScript.js'}, function(){
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {myMessage: message.myMessage});
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew that it was something about order.